# Amount of logical combinations

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

I have the following variables:

```
$start_t = 1;
$start_n = 2;
$end_t = 6;
$end_n = 5;
```

I want to check all the logical combinations between the $start_t and $start_n AND $end_t and $end_n.

I have the following:

```
if($start_t >= $start_n && $end_t >= end_n)
{ // Do stuff }
elseif($start_t < $start_n && $end_t >= $end_n)
{ // Do stuff }
elseif($start_t >= $start_n && $end_t < $end_n)
{ // Do stuff }
elseif($start_t < start_n && $end_t < $end_n)
{ // Do stuff }
```

Is there any other combination that I cannot see? I mean between the $start_t, $start_n And $end_t and $end_n.

Is there any way to calculate all the available combinations?

Comment: what about when they are equal? `$start_t == $start_n`

Comment: It depends on the conditional and logical operators you want to use. Assuming it's only greater than / less than and logical && operator I think only those 4 are the combinations

Comment: sorry you are right. I will now change the example above

Comment: I just made the code modification. Now it seems to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality case (`$start_t === $start_n`, similar for `$end_*`) is missing. Otherwise, all combinations are there.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using a binary operator, you have 2! = 2 permutations of the start variables, and for each one, 2! = 2 permutations of the end variables. So, in total you have 2!*2! = 4 combinations, assuming you don't need to test for equality. This proves that your code tests for every case.

Answer (score 2):

```
        if($start_t >= $start_n)
        {
            if($end_t >= end_n)
                //do stuff
            else
                //do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            if($end_t >= end_n)
                //do stuff
            else
                //do stuff
        }
```

Re structuring like this will help you to identify the combinations better. You can later refactor this back to your original format